# How can I delete the last word written in the text file

Tags: python, kivy

If I press Enter in text input I want to delete this enter line and not the whole text.

In this code will erase everything in txt file.

```
def line_delete(self):
    open('read.txt', 'w').close()
```

Comment: Read the text file into a string, and write a file without the last word

Comment: I am a beginner how am I supposed to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open the txt file into a string and then remove the last word from the string by changing the string into a list. Then you can remove the last element from the list and turn it back into a string with a for loop to attach all list elements back into one string variable.

Something like this:

```
def remove_last_word(string):
    string = "Hello Big World oops"
    string.split() = wordlist
    wordlist = wordlist.pop(len(wordlist)-1)
    newstring = ""
    for word in wordlist:
        newstring = newstring + " " + word
    return newstring
```

Comment: If this is the answer you needed could you please click the checkmark on the left?
If not please specify your question.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but where should i give the txt file name

Comment: This is just a function to remove the last word from the string. If you want to remove the last word from a txt file you load it in as a string and execute the function. The you overwrite the txt file again.

Comment: You can look up how to load in a txt file as a string